# Adding Product Doesn't show Tax (Woocommerce/Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am adding a product (after the customer has paid - on woocommerce_thankyou ) using:

```
$order->add_product( wc_get_product($mini_id), 1); // Add Minis
```

But this leaves the product's tax field empty on woocommerce dashboard:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$order->calculate_taxes();
```

This sorted it.